# Secure APIs using Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth

I want to write REST API using Node.js.

Part of my API needs additional security, It cannot be called directly from the browser or any other client. The client needs to send some authentication data along with the request. The Node.js server has to process the request and send response if the request is valid.

Do I want to look for OAuth libraries or is there any other libraries simpler than OAuth?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use expressjs auth: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/auth

Comment: What are your security requirements?
Who can access your API, what tool are they using?

Answer (score 1):

A simple OAuth can be found here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize. However I have no experience with this particular module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://passportjs.org/ as it allows you to use a lot of login options...